# How do I setup a list of test organizations with my new DBContext?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, testing

I have an application with uses multiple contexts for EF, some are code first, some server first, and all are dynamic.
I have a class that I call to get these contexts in my app.
Each context implements an interface such as:

```
public interface IDatabaseContextSwitcher
{
    IVGSContext GetDatabase(string organization);
    IVGSContext GetDatabase(Guid organizationGuid, string email);
    IVGSServerConn GetServerDatabase(string databaseName);
    IAuthContext GetAuthorizationDatabase();
}
```

I therefore has a class that implments the instances of these interfaces in the application. (VGSContext, VGSServerConn, and AuthContext).

I am trying to test these in my test project. I have made new classes from the interfaces with the plan to plug in some DbSets into these new classes and then test that my controllers do the correct thing.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to initialize the DBSets.

For example the following dies on Add:

```
 public AuthContextForTesting()
    {


        Organizations.Add(new Organization()
            {OrganizationName = "Test1", PK_Organization = Guid.Parse("34CE4F83-B3C9-421B-B1F3-42BBCDA9A004")});
        var cnt = Organizations.Count();
    }
    public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
```

I tried to initialize the DBSet with:
Organizations=new DbSet();
But it gives an error that this is not allowed due to permissions.

How do I set up my initial dbsets in code for my tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to do this, you first have to derive a class from DBSet. Sadly, my app uses both Core EF and EF 6 so I had to create 2 classes.

EF 6 Class

```
public class FakeDbSet<T> : System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T>, IDbSet<T> where T : class
{
    List<T> _data;

    public FakeDbSet()
    {
        _data = new List<T>();
    }

    public override T Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Derive from FakeDbSet<T> and override Find");
    }

    public override T Add(T item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public override T Remove(T item)
    {
        _data.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }

    public override T Attach(T item)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public T Detach(T item)
    {
        _data.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }

    public override T Create()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>() where TDerivedEntity : class, T
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<TDerivedEntity>();
    }


    public List<T> Local
    {
        get { return _data; }
    }

    public override IEnumerable<T> AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        _data.AddRange(entities);
        return _data;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<T> RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        for (int i = entities.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            T entity = entities.ElementAt(i);
            if (_data.Contains(entity))
            {
                Remove(entity);
            }
        }

        return this;
    }

    Type IQueryable.ElementType
    {
        get { return _data.AsQueryable().ElementType; }
    }

    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression IQueryable.Expression
    {
        get { return _data.AsQueryable().Expression; }
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get { return _data.AsQueryable().Provider; }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The EF Core had to include some interfaces to work.

```
public class FakeCoreDbSet<T> : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<T> , IQueryable, IEnumerable<T> where T : class
{
    List<T> _data;

    public FakeCoreDbSet()
    {
        _data = new List<T>();
    }

    public override T Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Derive from FakeDbSet<T> and override Find");
    }

    public override EntityEntry<T> Add(T item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
        //return item;
        return null;
    }

    public override EntityEntry<T> Remove(T item)
    {
        _data.Remove(item);
        //return item;
        return null;
    }

    public override EntityEntry<T> Attach(T item)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public T Detach(T item)
    {
        _data.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }

    public IList GetList()
    {
        return _data.ToList();
    }
    //public override T Create()
    //{
    //    return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    //}

    public TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>() where TDerivedEntity : class, T
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<TDerivedEntity>();
    }
    public List<T> Local
    {
        get { return _data; }
    }


    public override void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        _data.AddRange(entities);
        //return _data;
    }

    public override void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        for (int i = entities.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            T entity = entities.ElementAt(i);
            if (_data.Contains(entity))
            {
                Remove(entity);
            }
        }

        // this;
    }

    Type IQueryable.ElementType
    {
        get { return _data.AsQueryable().ElementType; }
    }

    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression IQueryable.Expression
    {
        get { return _data.AsQueryable().Expression; }
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get { return _data.AsQueryable().Provider; }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

}
```

Once these were created I could use MockObjects to get to them.
Note _dbContextSwitcher is the class created with a Moq that calls the different databases.

```
var vgsdatabase = new Mock<IVGSContext>();
        var settings=new FakeCoreDbSet<Setting>();
        settings.Add(new Setting()
        {
            SettingID = "OrgPrivacy",
            PK_Setting = Guid.NewGuid(),
            UserID = "",
            Value = "No"

        });
        vgsdatabase.Setup(s => s.Setting).Returns(settings);
        _dbcontextSwitcher.Setup(s => s.GetDatabase(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(vgsdatabase.Object);
```